# context.fillStyle is not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to get the image to display but i am having problems with the context.fillStyle working. It should be a pacman but cannot get it to work. Any help with being able to fix this would be very appreciated.

```
        <canvas> id="canvas" width="600" height="600">
            <p>Sorry, your browser doesnt understand the canvas element</p>
        </canvas>

        <script>
            var canvas;
            var context;
            canvas = document.getelementbyid('canvas');
            context = canvas.getContent('2d');
            function drawCharacter() {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(118, 118);
                context.lineTo(227, 73);
                context.bezierCurveTo(209, 30, 167, 0, 118, 0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(53, 0, 0.5, 53, 0, 118);
                context.bezierCurveTo(0, 183, 53, 235, 118, 235);
                context.bezierCurveTo(159, 235, 195, 215, 216, 183);
                context.lineTo(118, 118);
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle() = "rgb(249, 243, 161)";
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(118, 60, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle() = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                context.fill();
            } 
            drawcharacter();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) is a property, not a method. Remove the parens:

```
context.fillStyle = "rgb(249, 243, 161)";
```